# Trying to remove git repo on ubuntu guest

Tags: git, ubuntu, virtualbox, ubuntu-13.04

I am trying to remove whole git repository from my local machine, but git prohibits to delete several files.

I've tried:

1. `rm -r folder`
2. It asked me do I want to delete some write-protected files? I've asked `y`.
3. Following message appeared:

   ```
   rm: cannot remove ‘.git/objects/08/fa4fcd8413b84a1605e1c4866cb2493daf4c4e’: Operation not permitted
   rm: cannot remove ‘.git/objects/96/de4fe9aa42239290cae341427649f2afbdab16’: Operation not permitted
   rm: cannot remove ‘.git/objects/fd/ed37600b5fe66e1a0d0e4355b387e56ca2638e’: Operation not permitted
   rm: cannot remove ‘.git/objects/pack/pack-cb277ab3b4a3510209a9784a76760e6281da5218.idx’: Operation not permitted
   rm: cannot remove ‘.git/objects/pack/pack-cb277ab3b4a3510209a9784a76760e6281da5218.pack’: Operation not permitted
   ```

The `ls` command showed that all local files were deleted. Then I tried `sudo rm -r .git` from that folder - same result.

Help me please delete that folder.

Comment: Use `ls -la` to check the exact permissions

Comment: FYI: Contrary to some pop culture in the US, `dat` is not a word.

Comment: Are these files on a network share, or some unusual non-disk mount? Otherwise, I don't see how `sudo rm -r` could fail.

Comment: It is mounted on ubuntu. I've made a folder, containing folder with that repo, shared between windows (host) and ubuntu (guest). I am using virtual box for such purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out. The problem was that on my host machine (windows 7 x64) this folder was allowed to read only. I disabled it, and removed it from the host machine. Sorry for not saying that it was mounted, and thanks for all replies : )

Answer (score 37):

1. Close any git clients that might be running.
2. Set the permissions to delete first:

   ```
   chmod -R 777 folder
   ```
3. Try to force the deletion:

   ```
   rm -rf folder
   ```

Comment: I got this same issue and with you answer it worked! Thank you!

Comment: _"Close any git clients that might be running"_ bingo! I had Atom open using the directory as a project - close any IDE too.

Comment: Thank you Worked for deleting Dir in a WSL.

Answer (score 3):

The following command may help:

```
chmod -R u+w folder/
```

Also make sure you own all the files which you're trying to remove:

```
chown -R $USER folder/
```

On Linux it may be also a file attribute (check by `lsattr`):

```
chattr -R -AacdDijsStu folder/
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, for some reason the user immutable flag (uchg) was switched on for everything in the .git folder. This fixed it:

```
chflags -R nouchg folder/
```

I could then delete with `rm -rf folder/`.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete using:

```
chattr -i -R <directory>
rm -rf <directory>
```