# fatal: not a git repository - GitKraken: could not find a compatible repo

Tags: git, gitkraken

I moved my whole git project from on pc to another. and now my when i try to open it with gitKraken i get the erro "could't find a compatible repository". The folder has inside an .git file. when i run git -status i get the error "fatal:not a git repository". Inside the .git file it has these 2 folders "objects  refs". Also inside refs it has "heads  remotes    tags". 
I don't know if that info helps but some problem must be with the .git folder.Also another info is that i was making local commits in that project folders,if that helps somehow. 
If someone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like there was an issue with the copy. Verify that you can run a `git status` in your old repository, then copy the full contents of the .git folder over again - making sure to include all sub-files and folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was Ben W said some files that were missing from .git. So i just re-Copied the files.
That actually happened to me due to another problem that im going to leave a link here [Trying to remove git repo on ubuntu guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207566/trying-to-remove-git-repo-on-ubuntu-guest) that was answered in stackoverflow